# Как изменить фон QLabel?

Tags: pyqt5, label, qss

Как изменить фон QLabel? У меня есть много лейблов, поэтому нужно каждому менять индивидуально.
Нужно поменять фон не всему класу QLabel, а индивидуально 1. Как получить класс определенного лейбла в каскадной таблице?

````
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

HEIGHT = 750
WIDTH = 1300
class Menu(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.menubar = parent.menuBar()
        self.file = self.menubar.addMenu('&Опции')


        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), '&Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(parent.close)

        self.file.addAction(self.exitAction)

    def addMenu(self, actionName, text, command, icon, shortcut=None, statusTip=None) :
        self.actionName = QAction(QIcon(icon), text, self)
        if shortcut:
            self.actionName.setShortcut(shortcut)
        if statusTip:
            self.actionName.setStatusTip(statusTip)
        self.actionName.triggered.connect(command)

        self.file.insertAction(self.exitAction, self.actionName)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.q = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
        self.r_w, self.r_h = self.q.width(), self.q.height()
        self.setGeometry(self.r_w/2-WIDTH/2, self.r_h/2-HEIGHT/2, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        self.w = self.size().width()
        self.h = self.size().height()
        print(self.w, self.h)
        self.setFixedSize(1300, 750)
        self.setWindowTitle('Lings')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Lings.ico'))
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("sdsd", self)
        self.labelAnswer = QtWidgets.QLabel("", self)
        self.l_w, self.l_h = 500, 100
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelAnswer.resize(self.l_w, self.l_h)
        self.labelAnswer.move(self.w/2-self.l_w/2, 250)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.resize(self.l_w, self.l_h)
        self.label.move(self.w/2-self.l_w/2, 100)
        self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Verdana', 24))
        self.labelAnswer.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Verdana', 24))
        self.label.setStyleSheet(".QLabel{\n"        //Нужно поменять фон не всему класу QLabel, а индивидуально 1. Как получить класс определенного лейбла в каскадной таблице?
        "background-color: #E0FFFF\n"
        "\n"
        "}")
        self.label.setStyleSheet(".QLabel{\n"
        "background-color: #E0FFFF\n"
        "\n"
        "}")
        self.menu = Menu(self)
        self.menu.addMenu('action', 'New', lambda: SecondWindow(self), 'test.ico', shortcut="Ctrl+D", statusTip="Creating")




        self.show()

class SecondWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.q = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
        self.r_w, self.r_h = self.q.width(), self.q.height()
        self.setGeometry(self.r_w/2-WIDTH/2, self.r_h/2-HEIGHT/2, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Lings2')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Lings.ico'))
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(5):
            but = QtWidgets.QPushButton('button {}'.format(i), self)
            self.mainLayout.addWidget(but)
            self.buttons.append(but)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)


        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде индивидуально вот так:

```
self.label1.setStyleSheet("background-color: #E0FFFF")
self.label2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FF0000")
self.label3.setStyleSheet("background-color: #00FFFF")
```

В qss так:

```
QLabel#label1 {
    background-color: #E0FFFF;
}

QLabel#label2 {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Загрузить внешний qss-файл можно так (допустим, он называется style.qss и
лежит рядом с запускаемым py-файлом):

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
styleFile="style.qss"
with open(styleFile,"r") as sf:
    app.setStyleSheet(sf.read())
```

Comment: Почему то код не работает, если просто ```QLabel {
    background-color: #E0FFFF;
}``` , то работает, если ```QLabel#label1 {
    background-color: #E0FFFF;
}``` - нет

Comment: @Injustive должно работать. Если во во внешнем файле qss, то все нормально работает